What css would display format the html correctly
My html output should be:

image should be in the left
description in the right
meta in the bottom right under the description
Also image should be 30% of total width and height of image should be same as width of image.

The width and heigh of image should always be same, but I am stuck. Please suggest what can I try next?
<div id="root">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum title</h1>
    <div class='outer-parent'>
        <img class='image-parent' src=,some_image> />

        <div class='text-parent'>
          <span class='description'>
              In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a 
              placeholder text commonly used to
              demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface 
              without relying on 
              meaningful content. Lorem ipsum may be used as a 
              placeholder before final copy is 
              available.
          </span>
          <span class="meta">Published: 12/12/2012 | Views: 22</span>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>

The below css , I have tried
.title {
  text-align: center;
}
.outer-parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.text-parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 70%;
    margin-left: 1%;
}
.image-parent {
    max-width: 30%;
    height: auto;
}
.text-parent span:nth-of-type(2) {
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.text-parent span:nth-of-type(1) {
  flex-grow: 2;
}


if my answer helped you it would be nice if you coould accept it.

I have a codepen link https://codepen.io/Sonal-the-bold/pen/VwJLQBJ?editors=1100.     Hope this helps

Have  a look if this is what you were looking for:


.outer-parent {
display: flex;
}

.text-parent {
width: 68%;
margin-left: 2%;

}

.image-div {
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300');
  width: 30%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: auto;
  aspect-ratio : 1 / 1;
}

.meta {
display: block;
}
<div id="root">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum title</h1>
    <div class='outer-parent'>
        <div class="image-div"></div>

    <div class='text-parent'>
      <p class='description'>
        In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to
        demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on 
        meaningful content. Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is 
        available.
      </p>
      <span class="meta">Published: 12/12/2012 | Views: 22</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




Hi Snake, thanks for the response. I was trying to upvote your answer, because it helped little bit, but I am not able to upvote.

@Sonal You accepted my answer which is also fine for me. Let me know if you need further assistance.
